# Sort lines to form a unique words dictionary listing

Tags: command-line, python, forum

Many a times we build dictionaries in online forums for typical words used in a forum, the user responds in following format in a phpbb forum

term: defination

hence the job is to collect all these unique entries eliminating noise , we typically copy the entire page and sort it to remove the noise:

```
Joined: Fri Jan 24, 2014 9:49 pm
Joined: Fri Jun 05, 2009 5:57 pm
Joined: Mon Jul 07, 2014 7:20 am
Joined: Mon Jul 07, 2014 7:20 am
Joined: Mon Nov 25, 2013 6:46 am

Posts: 49
Posts: 49
Posts: 49
Posts: 49
Posts: 5
Posts: 8152
Progessium: A light peptide necoliye
```

So how can a command line  or a python script  sort the above contents removing noise and only getting entries in alphabetical order like:

> Progessium: A light peptide necoliye

Comment: http://nejc.skoberne.net/2011/02/phpbb-export-all-posts-for-a-user-into-a-file/

Comment: we dont have admin access to it, just want to scrape the html

Comment: https://gist.github.com/evandhoffman/2030469

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620875/how-to-download-all-posts-of-phpbb3-forum-if-i-am-not-admin

Comment: Use Adobe Acrobat Pro, as variant)